# Get form filed by using reference

Tags: javascript, extjs, reference, extjs6, formpanel

I have a form as follows

```
this.stdForm  = new Ext.form.Panel(this.createStdForm());
this.stdForm.getForm().load({
     params: { action: 'load', id: 1234, dep: 'std' },
     success: this.formLoaded,
     scope: this
});

createStdForm: function () {    
    var flds = {
       items: [
           { fieldLabel: 'Roll Number', name: 'ROLL_NUMBER', xtype: 'displayfield' } }
       ]
    };

    var fldSet = {
       title: 'Student Information',
       xtype: 'panel',
       defaultType: 'fieldset',
       defaults: { autoHeight: true, baseCls: 'x-fieldset-noborder', reference:'RollNumber'},
       items: [flds]
    };

    return {
        layout: 'column',          
        border: false,
        defaults: {                           
           border: false
        },                        
        url: this.getUrl(),
        items: [
           col1
        ]
     };    
}
```

and on formloaded function, I am trying to get reference of roll number field

```
formLoaded:function (form, action) {
  form.getreferences('RollNumber') // not working
  form.lookupreference(); // not working
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d7m here is the short fiddle explaining what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In your example - just add [`referenceHolder: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.mixin.Container.html#cfg-referenceHolder) to the panel:

> If `true`, this container will be marked as being a point in the
>   hierarchy where references to items with a specified reference config
>   will be held. The container will automatically become a
>   referenceHolder if a controller is specified. See the introductory
>   docs for `Ext.container.Container` for more information about references
>   & reference holders.

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d7t